Why is null not automatically inferred as a return type in a React Native (w Expo) project?
I think I have the tsconfig misconfigured, because this can't be right, can it??
In my react native app with an expo config, null is not automatically inferred:

here's the config
{
    "compilerOptions": {},
    "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
}

This isn't an issue for my web projects, where typescript correctly infers the return types (true | null ).


Have you enabled strictNullChecks?

enabled strict for everything (otherwise what's even the point!) thank you @VLAZ
